# How to update rows based on one field/column on two tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to update one table using another table on field "Id" such that it wont create duplicates

let say my first table is **Table1** and second table is **Table2** . I would like to update the row in **Table1** from **Table2** when the Id is matching

I am aware of using UNION function but this applies to entire columns where I only need to consider a single column. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/operators-query.html#union-all

Example of my Tables

**Table1**

```
Id  name    number  value
1   a        8       100
2   b        8       100
3   c        8       100
4   d        8       100
```

**Table2**

```
Id  name    number  value
3   c         8      99
4   d         6      100
5   e         7      100
```

**Expected output**

```
Id  name    number  value
1   a        8       100
2   b        8       100
3   c        8        99
4   d        6       100
5   e        7       100
```

Please note that in the output table row with Id 3,4 has be updated and new Id 5 is inserted.

PS: It would be better if someone could provide me the  **select statement** to get the output table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constuct you are searching for is called [MERGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE trg(Id INT, name VARCHAR,   number INT, value INT)
AS    SELECT 1   ,'a',        8,       100
UNION SELECT 2   ,'b',        8,       100
UNION SELECT 3   ,'c',        8,       100
UNION SELECT 4   ,'d',        8,       100;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE src(Id INT, name VARCHAR,   number INT, value INT)
AS    SELECT 3   ,'c',         8,      99
UNION SELECT 4   ,'d',         6,      100
UNION SELECT 5   ,'e',         7,      100;
```

Query:

```
MERGE INTO trg
USING src
  ON trg.Id = src.Id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET name = src.name,
                             number = src.number,
                             value = src.value
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID, name, number, value) 
                      VALUES (src.Id, src.name, src.number, src.value);

SELECT * FROM trg;
```

Output:

[image]

---

## EDIT:

> *PS: It would be better if someone could provide me the select statement to get the output table.*

UNION ALL combined with QUALIFY could be used:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 1 AS priority FROM trg
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *, 0 AS priority FROM src
)
SELECT Id, Name, Number, Value
FROM cte
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Priority) = 1
ORDER BY Id;
```

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful explanation

Comment: @Py1996 Glad to hear I could help :)